# Stuffed up sudoers file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

I have managed to stuff up my sudoers file and am locked out of my server.  Is there any way to get back in?

To be precise, I have a single user (call her `jane`), who used to have sudo privileges for anything.  In attempting to make a sudo command not require a password for `jane`, I changed a line that read

```
jane ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

to

```
jane ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD= some command
```

The result of this is that `jane` can no longer run *any* commands with sudo.  All commands result in

```
Sorry, user jane is not allowed to run '/bin/cat' as root on mybox.
```

or something similar.

I have locked down `root`, so that I can't ssh into it, and have even disabled it.  I can't `sudo su` for the same reason as above.

Is there any way to get a user with sudo privileges again, or am I stuck forever.

Final thing is that I don't have physical access to the server, so can't plug in a recovery disk and edit `sudoers` manually.

Comment: short answer is no. you have to boot single user or rescue disk.

Comment: Don't you have remote console access? (iLO, iDRAC, KVM, Lish, VNC, guy living in a datacenter)

Comment: I have ssh into `jane`, and some sort of remote console (from my service provider) via VMWare, I believe.